# Generalize \@ifnextchar to consider more than one character.

Tags: tex-core

I am looking for a clever way to write a `switch` statement based on the next input characters, ideally, one could write:

```
\@switchnextchars
       \@case{abc}{\typeout{You gave me an abc}}%
       \@case{ab+}{\typeout{You gave me an ab+}}%
       \@default{\typeout{Nothing that I heard of!}%
 \@endswitch
```

but also

```
\@ifnextchars{abc}{yes code}{no code}
```

or even

```
\@ifnexttwochars{ab}{yes code}{no code}
```

would be useful.

Comment: Something like `\@ifnextchars` got already implemented, I think even twice, but I can't recall where right now. Was it `beamer`, `pgf/tikz` or *koma script*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible approach to construct a loop of `\@ifnextchar` tests, for example

```
\makeatletter
\newtoks\my@toksa
\newtoks\my@toksb
\newcommand\@ifnextchars[3]{%
  \def\my@tempa{#1}%
  \def\my@tempb{#2}%
  \def\my@tempc{#3}%
  \def\my@tempd{}%
  \@ifnextchars@aux@i
}
\newcommand*\@ifnextchars@aux@i{%
  \def\my@tempe{\expandafter\my@tempb\my@tempd}%
  \ifx\@empty\my@tempa\@empty
  \else
    \def\my@tempe{\@ifnextchars@aux@ii}%
  \fi
  \my@tempe  
}
\newcommand*\@ifnextchars@aux@ii{%
  \my@toksa\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    {\expandafter\@car\my@tempa\@nil}%
  \expandafter\@ifnextchar\the\my@toksa
    {%
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\@ifnextchars@aux@iii\the\my@toksa{%
        \my@toksb\expandafter{\my@tempd}%
        \edef\my@tempd{\the\my@toksb\the\my@toksa}%
        \my@toksa\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          {\expandafter\@cdr\my@tempa\@nil}%
        \edef\my@tempa{\the\my@toksa}%  
        \@ifnextchars@aux@i
      }%
      \@ifnextchars@aux@iii
    }
    {\expandafter\my@tempc\my@tempd}%
}
\makeatother
```

(This may well not be the most efficient implementation for this.) As you can see, this is non-trivial as TeX only provides `\futurelet` (on which `\@ifnextchar` is built), and this only deals with one token at a time. The 'cases' system is doable but will not be pretty, as each case would have to be saved and the tests done one at a time with token-reinsertion.

Comment: This is a clever solution. Thanks. But have you considered catcode changes between your command definition and later use/argument grabbing? Also, can we avoid repeat calls to `\@ifnextchar` for each character in the test set? I await your comment before having a go at it.

Comment: @Pluto: not really clever, more brute force. As you probably known, `\@ifnextchar` does an `\ifx` test, and so only gives a positive result if category codes are unchanged. So it seems to make logical sense if an extended `\@ifnextchars` behaves in the same way. You could implement `\my@ifnextchar` using an `\if` test to use only character code, then use that function in my solution to do this for multiple characters.

Comment: @Pluto. On the question of multiple uses of `\@ifnextchar` in the above, remember that we are using `\futurelet` to 'see' the next token. If we want to 'see' several tokens, this does mean that we have to remove them from the input stream. The  approach of absorbing them all in one go first fails with something like `{a}bc` (_i.e._ the test will return true when it should be false). So doing the job one token at a time is the only safe way: sorry.

Comment: I will prefer the `\my@ifnextchar` to avoid possible changes/differences in catcode between the test set and what is found on the input stack. `\@ifnextchar` seems to be more expensive than simply grabbing the next character and making a comparison. See my attempt below. Not really tested yet.

Answer (score 6):

`xstring` package provides some functions for string operation, `\IfStrEqCase` can be used for this purpose. Using pdfTeX (`latex` command is often pdfTeX), you can also use `\pdfstrcmp` for comparation. This does not work as `\@ifnextchar`, but may be helpful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\test[1]{%
  \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
    {a}{I got `a'}
    {bb}{I got `bb'}
    {ccc}{I got `ccc'}}%
    [I got unknown string]\par}

\test{a}     % I got `a'
\test{bb}    % I got `bb'
\test{ccc}   % I got `ccc'
\test{other} % I got unknown string
\end{document}
```

---

Besides, it is difficult to generalize `\@ifnextchar` for alphabets. TeX cannot distinguish `\foo` + `ab` from a single command `\fooab`.

You can define several commands begin with `\foo`, but each one should ends with alphabets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\strlist{a,bb,ccc}
\@for\curstr:=\strlist\do{%
  \long\expandafter\edef \csname test\curstr\endcsname
    {I got `\curstr'.\par}%
}
\makeatother

\testa   % I got `a'
\testbb  % I got `bb'
\testccc % I got `ccc'

\end{document}
```

---

Using `etextools`, you can partially generalize `\@ifnextchar` to multiple charcter (non-alphabets or alphabets are allowed). This is the closest one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etextools}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
\def\test{%
  \futuredef[-+ab]\nexttokens{%
    \IfStrEqCase{\nexttokens}{%
      {-}{I got `-'}
      {-+}{I got `-+'}
      {+ab}{I got `+ab'}}%
      [I got unknown string]\par}}

\test-   % I got `-'
\test-+  % I got `-+'
\test+ab % I got `+ab'
\test++ab  % I got unknown string
\test a  % I got unknown string

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation on Joseph Wright's solution. `\ifstrcmpTF` compares strings of characters irrespective of their catcodes.

```
\makeatletter
\usepackage{catoptions}
\newcommand\@ifnextchars[3]{%
  \def\@tempa{#1}\def\@tempb{#2}%
  \def\@tempc{#3}\def\@tempd{}%
  \@ifnextchars@a
}
\def\@ifnextchars@a#1{%
  \toks@\cptthreexp{\expandafter\@car\@tempa\@nil}%
  \expandafter\ifstrcmpTF\expandafter{\the\toks@}{#1}{%
    \edef\@tempd{\expandcsonce\@tempd\the\toks@}%
    \toks@\cptthreexp{\expandafter\@cdr\@tempa\@nil}%
    \edef\@tempa{\the\toks@}%
    \ifcsemptyTF\@tempa{\expandafter\@tempb\@tempd}%
    \@ifnextchars@a
  }{%
    \edef\@tempd{\expandcsonce\@tempd#1}%
    \expandafter\@tempc\@tempd
  }%
}

\begin{document}
% Tests
\@ifnextchars{abc}{yes}{no} abc

\@ifnextchars{abc}{yes}{no} acb

\@ifnextchars{abc}{yes}{no} cba
\end{document}
```

There is an expandable form of `\@ifnextchar,` by Chervet Florent. Can we think of an expandable form of `\@ifnextchars?`

Comment: You know, I assume, that an expandable test for characters is more restricted than one using `\futurelet` (for example, try `\@ifnextchars{abc}{yes}{no}{a}bc` in your implementation).

Comment: @Joseph: I can see your argument. Thanks. My code will wrongly yield `true` in this case. Only `\futurelet` can save the situation, but how often do we need to test _abc_ against _{a}bc_? Well, I (like you) normally prefer to consider all bizarre possibilities.

Comment: As I'm on the LaTeX3 Team, these edge cases worry me (or at least, they worry Frank M., who then worries me!). I mention it because we had some discussion about `xparse`, and what was and was not possible for expandable 'look ahead' functions in TeX. The documentation for that package lists various limitations of an expandable look-ahead, including the fact that you can't do a definition with a terminal optional argument and have it work expandably. So for robustness it's necessary to stick with `\futurelet`-based code.

Comment: @Joseph: You’re right! But I have found some good and robust applications for expandable `\@ifnextchar;` not for **terminal optional arguments** anyway. Already I am able to preserve outer braces in argument grabbing, which is the source of your trepidation about my solution. Do you have further concerns with that solution?

Comment: @Joseph: OK, `\futurelet` is inevitable in this game. But your solution fails for `\@ifnextchars{{a}bc}{yes -> }{no -> } {a}bc`. See my next rather acrobatic (but cheap) solution, which works in all cases I have tested.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\makeatletter
\def\special@car{\futurelet\next\special@car@a}
\long\def\special@car@a#1#2\car@nil{%
  \ifxTF\next\temp@bgroup{\toks@{{#1}}}{\toks@{#1}}%
}
\long\def\@ifnextchars#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
  \let\temp@bgroup\bgroup
  \let\bgroup\@undefined
  \def\@tempa{#1}\def\@tempb{#2}%
  \def\@tempc{#3}\def\@tempd{}%
  \@ifnextchars@a
}
\def\@ifnextchars@a{\futurelet\next\@ifnextchars@b}
\def\@ifnextchars@b{%
  \ifxTF\next\@sptoken{\afterassignment\@ifnextchars@a\let\next= }%
  \@ifnextchars@c
}
\def\@ifnextchars@c#1{%
  \ifxTF\next\temp@bgroup{\toks1{{#1}}}{\toks1{#1}}%
  \expandafter\special@car\@tempa\car@nil
  \edef\x{{\the\toks@}{\the\toks1}}%
  \expandafter\ifstrcmpTF\x{%
    \edef\@tempd{\expandcsonce\@tempd\the\toks@}%
    \toks@\cptthreexp{\expandafter\cpt@cdr\@tempa\cdr@nil}%
    \edef\@tempa{\the\toks@}%
    \ifcsemptyTF\@tempa{\cptthreexp\endgroup\expandafter\@tempb\@tempd}%
    \@ifnextchars@a
  }{%
    \edef\@tempd{\expandcsonce\@tempd\the\toks1}%
    \cptthreexp\endgroup\expandafter\@tempc\@tempd
  }%
}


\begin{document}

{\tt
abc: \@ifnextchars{abc}{yes -> }{no -> } abc

\detokenize{{a}bc}: \@ifnextchars{{a}bc}{yes -> }{no -> } {a}bc

\detokenize{a{b}c}: \@ifnextchars{a{b}c}{yes -> }{no -> } a{b}c

abc: \@ifnextchars{abc}{yes -> }{no -> } {c}ba
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a tangential comment, but I notice that you have basically a whole 'nother API based around macro programming inside catoptions. Have you looked into using expl3 or etoolbox before? The chances of running into problems using tested code is much lower. (Also, TeX gets slower the more control sequences there are, so defining many redundant commands tends towards inefficiency.)

Comment: @Will: The _catoptions_ package provides an email address that can be used for forwarding comments to its author. I think that is where your comments on _catoptions_ should go. I am sure the author will welcome your comments.

Comment: are you saying you're not the author of that package? But you're right this isn't the best place to discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of trickery by embedding an `\ifnextchar` inside another `\ifnextchar`. Then when that worked, I embedded yet another one inside the second one, so now it considers three characters. My goal was to typeset a single Greek letter with extra space around it, unless the next character was a comma, period, or dash.

Here is the code.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\singlegreekletter}[1]{%
\hspace{1mm}{\begin{greek}{#1}\end{greek}\hspace{1mm}}%
% three nested ifnextchar commands
\@ifnextchar{.}{\nolinebreak\hspace{-.1em}}%
{\@ifnextchar{,}{\nolinebreak\hspace{-.1em}}%
{\@ifnextchar{-}{\nolinebreak\hspace{-.1em}}{ }}}% keep space
}%
\makeatother
```