# Trying to understand how \@cdr...\@nil works in relation to \expandafter

Tags: macros, errors

I am trying to define a macro `\@ifnextchars` with three arguments, the first argument being a list of characters, which expands to either the second or the third argument depending on whether one of the character of the first argument follows the command.
Here follows a minimalistic example of what I have done and how I would like to use it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@ifnextchars[3]{%
    \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\@empty#1\@empty%
        \def\@ifnextchars@tmp{#3}%
    \else%
        \def\@ifnextchars@tmp{%
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@ifnextchars@aux\expandafter%
                {\@car#1\@nil}{\@cdr#1\@nil}{#2}{#3}%
        }%
    \fi%
    \@ifnextchars@tmp%
}
\newcommand\@ifnextchars@aux[4]{%
    \expandafter\@ifnextchar#1{%
        #3%
    }{%
        \@ifnextchars{#2}{#3}{#4}%
    }%
}

\newcommand\whereinsentence{%
    \@ifnextchars{.!?}{%
        I am in the end of a sentence.
    }{%
        I am not in the end of a sentence.
    }%
}
\newcommand\vowel{%
    \@ifnextchars{aeiouy}{%
        Vowel:
    }{%
        Not vowel:
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here is \whereinsentence a sentence\whereinsentence.

\vowel a.

\vowel b.

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn’t compile:

```
Runaway argument?
{I am in the end of a sentence. }{\@ifnextchars {\@cdr \@cdr .!?\@nil \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@cdr was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.44
```

My guess is that `\@cdr` didn’t expand when needed. I find this strange because I made sure to expand my `\@cdr` with `\expandafter`…
So I guess that I do not understand well how `\expandafter` works ☹
Can someone help me?

I was inspired by this post: [Generalize \@ifnextchar to consider more than one character.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10512/generalize-ifnextchar-to-consider-more-than-one-character)
However, this last post was about creating a variant of `\@ifnextchar` looking for entire word. I am just interested in knowing whether one of the given characters are present directly afterwards.

I have made this `\ifx` yielding a `\def` to make sure that the `\@ifnextchar` does not react with the `\fi`. I do not find this very satisfying: if anyone has a better solution, I am welcoming it with pleasure ☺

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to look at `\@addpunct` defined in `amsthm.sty`. You're expanding `\@car`, but not `\@cdr`.

Comment: Thanks @egreg ☺ The example I gave was more a minimal example than what I really wanted to do, so `\@addpunct` is of few aid for what I am trying to do. But thanks ☺

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot expand the second argument like that. Here's a simple way with the help of eTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@ifnextchars[3]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \def\@ifnextchars@tmp{#3}%
  \else
    \edef\@ifnextchars@tmp{%
      \noexpand\@ifnextchars@aux
        {\unexpanded\expandafter{\@car#1\@nil}}
        {\unexpanded\expandafter{\@cdr#1\@nil}}
        \unexpanded{{#2}{#3}}%
    }%
  \fi
  \@ifnextchars@tmp
}
\newcommand\@ifnextchars@aux[4]{%
  \@ifnextchar{#1}{%
    #3%
  }{%
    \@ifnextchars{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  }%
}

\newcommand\whereinsentence{%
  \@ifnextchars{.!?}{%
    I am in the end of a sentence.
  }{%
    I am not in the end of a sentence.
  }%
}
\newcommand\vowel{%
  \@ifnextchars{aeiouy}{%
    Vowel:
  }{%
    Not vowel:
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here is \whereinsentence a sentence\whereinsentence.

\vowel a.

\vowel b.

\end{document}
```

Comment: To be safe, you should define the command with `\protected\def\@ifnextchars#1#2#3` or with `\newrobustcmd` from `etoolbox` package, or just go with `\DeclareRobustCommand`, but I would go for the first two options.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you are expanding `\@car`, but not `\@cdr`, because the chain of `\expandafter`s doesn't reach it.

Here's an implementation in `expl3` that you may enjoy studying.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \bodin_ifnext_chars:nnnn
 {
  \tl_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } #2
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ifnextchars}{mmmm}
 {
  \bodin_ifnext_chars:nnnn { #1 } { #4 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\whereinsentence{%
    \ifnextchars{.!?}{%
        ``I am in the end of a sentence.''
    }{%
        ``I am not in the end of a sentence.''
    }%
}
\newcommand\vowel{%
    \ifnextchars{aeiouy}{%
        Vowel:
    }{%
        Not vowel:
    }%
}

\begin{document}

Here is \whereinsentence a sentence\whereinsentence.

\vowel a.

\vowel b.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am afraid that I don’t understand something about the semantics of `\expandafter`, then :-\
I thought that `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\a expandafter\b\c` first unfolds `\c`, then `\b`, then `\a`. Is because of the curly braces that it breaks?

I was not aware about `expl3`. When I will have time, I shall definitely look for it ☺ Thanks!

Comment: @MartinBodin `\expandafter` eventually acts on a *single* token, not on a braced group.

Comment: Oh. I see. Then I guess that it would work if I make local definitions of the \@car and \@cdr. Is it right?
I am going to test as soon as I can. Thanks ☺