# What do \@nil, \@cdr and \@car mean

Tags: macros, latex-base

Today I came across these three commands:

```
\@nil
\@cdr
\@car
```

Some are mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195581/what-does-car-do) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320696/trying-to-understand-how-cdr-nil-works-in-relation-to-expandafter), but I didn't get the idea of it. It seems to have to do with the macro character.

I haven't seen any description about it on google and TeX.SX.

Comment: I retagged from tex-core to latex-base as these are latex macros

Comment: This question explains them quite well: [Lisp relics in LaTeXe logo](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5048/2693)

Comment: @AlanMunn ooh it does but this one has a better title

Comment: That's probably the reason I haven't found it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the names come from lisp.

In lisp, car returns the head of a list, cdr returns the tail of a list and nil is an empty list.

---

in latex

```
\def\@car#1#2\@nil{#1}
\def\@cdr#1#2\@nil{#2}
```

(`\@nil` is not defined at all)

so

```
\@car abc\@nil
```

expands to `a`

and

```
\@cdr abc\@nil
```

expands to `bc`

Comment: In `expl3` lingo, `\tl_head:n {abc}` and `\tl_tail:n {abc}`

Comment: But how does this work, if `\@nil` is undefined. Why is there no undefined error?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz tokens only make an undefined error if you try to expand them. tokens used to delimit a macro argument are not expanded, try `\def\foo#1\wibblethingy{hello #1}...\foo Maestro\wibblethingy`

Comment: @egreg we should put in a change request `\tl_car:n` and `tl_cdr:n` to honour the cultural heritage

Comment: Aaaaah. Good to know.

Comment: @UlrichDiez yes they are only really usable in internal code where you have tight control over the input arguments

Comment: @MaestroGlanz Be aware that with `\@car`and `\@cdr` the first argument is an undelimited argument and thus leading space tokens might get discarded silently and that pairs of braces surrounding the entire first argument and/or the entire second argument get silently removed. Not always the desired behaviour.

Comment: @UlrichDiez If I try `\@cdr abc de\@nil`, the result is `bc de`. There isn't any space eaten up. It is exactly, what I expect.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz I use the symbol ␣ for denoting a space. Try `\expandafter\@cdr\@firstofone{␣}abcde\@nil` and you will get `bcde`as the space token delivered by `\@firstofone` will not be taken into account when `\@cdr` "fetches" its first argument. Discarding leading space tokens is standard behaviour when TeX "fetches" undelimited arguments. But it is not standard behaviour when TeX fetches delimited arguments. Therefore `\expandafter\@cdr\@firstofone{␣}a␣bcde\@nil` will deliver `␣bcde` instead of `a␣bcde` and `\expandafter\@car\@firstofone{␣}a␣bcde\@nil` will deliver `a` instead of `␣`.