# Check if at least one substring in a list can be found in a string

Tags: conditionals, characters, comparison

There are several solutions both integrated in TeX and proposed on this side for checking if a substring can be found in a given string (such as `IfSubStr`, `IfStringInList` and others).
As for example, `\instringTF` (as defined here:https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26873/61517) when used as

```
\instringTF{graph}{graphs}{We have data}{We do not have data}
```

gives

```
We have data
```

Now, I would like to extend that to several possible substrings, i.e. to a call such as

```
\instringTF{graph,images}{graphs}{We have data}{We do not have data}
```

This should still evaluate to

```
We have data
```

while

```
\instringTF{graph,images}{image}{We have data}{We do not have data}
```

should evaluate to

```
We do not have data
```

Are there solutions for that issue, too?

Edit: Peter Grill suggested using a solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350818/61517. I implemented it, resulting in:

```
\documentclass[%
reprint,
amsfonts,
floatfix,
amsmath,amssymb,
aps,
pra,
]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
%\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
%\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{todonotes}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{substr}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{\tikzexternaldisable\@todo[#1]{#2}\tikzexternalenable}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \grill_str_multicase:nnTF
{
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__grill_str_multicase_cases_seq { } { #2 }
    \tl_clear:N \l__grill_str_multicase_cases_tl
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 2 } { \seq_count:N \l__grill_str_multicase_cases_seq }
    {
        \seq_set_split:Nnx \l__grill_str_multicase_subcases_seq { }
        { \seq_item:Nn \l__grill_str_multicase_cases_seq { ##1 } }
        \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__grill_str_multicase_subcases_seq
        {
            \tl_put_right:Nx \l__grill_str_multicase_cases_tl
            {
                {\exp_not:n{####1}}{\seq_item:Nn \l__grill_str_multicase_cases_seq { ##1 + 1}}
            }
        }
    }
    \str_case:nVTF { #1 } \l__grill_str_multicase_cases_tl { #3 } { #4 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \grill_str_multicase:nn
{
    \grill_str_multicase:nnTF { #1 } { #2 } { } { }
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \grill_str_multicase:nnT
{
    \grill_str_multicase:nnTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { }
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \grill_str_multicase:nnF
{
    \grill_str_multicase:nnTF { #1 } { #2 } { } { #3 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\IfStringCaseX}{mmo}
{
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}
    { \grill_str_multicase:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
    { \grill_str_multicase:nnF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\ConditionalText}[1]{%
    \IfStringCaseX{#1}
    {
        {{images}{graphs}}
        {%
            We have images/graphs
        }
    }[{Error: Unknown parameter ``#1'' to ConditionalText}]%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \ConditionalText{images/subx.tikz}
    
    \ConditionalText{images}
\end{document}
```

Here, the first line containing

```
\ConditionalText{images/subx.tikz}
```

produces `Unknown parameter`, while the second line

```
\ConditionalText{images}
```

produces

```
We have images/graphs
```

i.e. the proposed solution does not work for my use case.

Comment: I think that the solutions at [Modified \IfStrEqCase with multiple matches per case](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/350815/4301) should work for you.

Comment: @PeterGrill Unfortunately, your solution does not work as I would expect it to work, ref. to my edit

Comment: The code checks for exact matches so needs to be adapted to  match substrings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map over the list of possible substring; if a match is found, break the mapping by setting the conditional to true.

Then check whether the conditional is true or false.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\instringTF}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = list of possible substrings, #2 = string, #3 = true text, #4 = false text
  \arclupus_instring:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\bool_new:N \l_arclupus_instring_bool

\cs_new_protected:Nn \arclupus_instring:nnnn
 {
  \bool_set_false:N \l_arclupus_instring_bool
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \str_if_in:nnT { #2 } { ##1 }
     {% ##1 is a substring, no need to check further
      \clist_map_break:n { \bool_set_true:N \l_arclupus_instring_bool }
     }
   }
  \bool_if:NTF \l_arclupus_instring_bool { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\instringTF{graph}{graphs}{We have data}{We do not have data}

\instringTF{graph,images}{graphs}{We have data}{We do not have data}

\instringTF{graph,images}{image}{We have data}{We do not have data}

\end{document}
```

[image]